# How are classes loaded during user interaction?

Tags: arrays, swift, class

Very new to swift here. I am trying to make a simple to-do app.

When a user types in an task, i wanna try to add this task to a string array and increase a counter.

When I type in multiple tasks, my string array only holds the previously typed in task and my counter always is 1 (counter is based off number of items in the string array).

I'm assuming that every time i type in a new task, my class which deals with my string array and counter is reset to their initial values which is an empty string array and 0 respectively.

Any idea how to avoid this, or how classes are loaded when it comes to user interaction?

Sorry if im not being too clear, thanks.

```
class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
...
var lastItem = 0
var tableViewData: Array<String> = []

...

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    tableViewData.append(textField.text!)
    lastItem = tableViewData.count
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}
```

ViewController main class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
...
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have, so it's easier to see where it's going wrong?

Comment: sorry, added some now

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `tableViewData` is a property of the `TextInputTableViewCell`. This means that every time the tableview is reloaded, you lose the contents that were stored in this variable. You can solve this by making the `UITableViewController` the `UITextFieldDelegate` and store the text in a property of the `UITableViewController`. You can do this when you load the `TextInputTableViewCell`. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var lastItem = 0
    var tableViewData: Array<String> = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Load your cell    
        let cell: TextInputTableViewCell = ... 

        // Set the text field delegate
        cell.textField.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        tableViewData.append(textField.text!)
        lastItem = tableViewData.count
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
}
```

So your `TextInputTableViewCell` should look like this:

```
class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

}
```

Comment: i don't use a UITableViewController, just a ViewController with a UITableView. I'm still kinda confuse what you mean with the last sentence. I added how I set up my ViewController class

Comment: I've added some code as an example. I'm assuming your `TextInputTableViewCell` has a UITextField called `textField`

Comment: in my `tablewView cellForRowAt` function i had already set up `cell.textField.delegate = cell` which seems to work fine

Comment: I know, but that means it will call the delegate function in the `TextInputTableViewCell`, which will store the array in there as well, which means every time the cell is reloaded all that data is gone.

Comment: I have tried to make it even clearer by rewriting the `TextInputTableViewCell` class and the `ViewController` class for you.

Comment: i got it now. thanks for your help. Do you know why the data gets lost when the TextInputTableViewCell class reloads and why it doesn't get lost when in the ViewController class?

Comment: That is because the `ViewController` doesn't get reinitialized.

Comment: is there any way to re-initialize the `View Controller` class within my `TextInputTableViewCell` class? So I can move the `textFieldShouldReturn` function back to the subclass?

Comment: No, that would be like putting your wardrobe in your clothes, instead of putting your clothes in your wardrobe